# DX12 Triangle not showing up

Tags: c++, direct3d12

I am trying to use DX12 to draw a Triangle in a Window with Visual C++.

For me everything seems to be in place required for it, and it is all working fine too, all DX12 Objects are created successfully, the Render Targets are cleared with the provided clear color, but the Triangle is not visible on the screen.

The weird thing about asking for help for it is that i get no errors besides that it is not doing what it should... why the only thing i can really do to give a picture about my issue, is to provide the entire [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odmxfUOdUtIRNEkM7ItJdf_sYpTQTyOi/view?usp=sharing), since i have no idea what the problem is, because i get no Compile, Runtime, or DX12 Erros (I have the Debug Layer Enabled with GPU Based Validation), and when checking everything with breakpoints step by step, nothing seemed wrong too.

Here a little overview and remarks about my VS-Project for better orientation

I have a singleton class called Process which holds all the functionality

The Process Execution is as followed:

1. Create Process (WinMain)
2. Execute Process::InitalizeProcess(), which is a function which creates the window and all used DX12 Objects
3. While Loops which Peeks Window Messages until Process::Quit() is called which terminates the Process, and cleans up

The Render() Function is executed when the WM_PAINT is Dispatched on the WinProc
in order to record and execute Command Lists on the Command Queue ...

I am using the D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT Flag on my RootSignature, in order to input the Vertex Buffer to the PSO

Edit:
Here the Minimal Reproducible Example Version of the Process::InitalizeProcess() and Process::Render() Functions

```cpp
int Process::InitalizeProcess(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //Window Creation Excluded for simplicity

    //Device & Adapter Creation Excluded for simplicity


    // Create Command Queue

    //Command Queue Description
    D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC queueDesc = {};
    queueDesc.Flags = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_FLAG_NONE;
    queueDesc.Type = D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT;

    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&commandQueue)),
        "Failed to create Command Queue")


    // Create Command Allocator

    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommandAllocator(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&commandAllocator)),
        "Failed to create Command Allocator")


    // Create Swapchain

    //Swapchain Description
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC SwapChainDesc = {};
    SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;

    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 900;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 600;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
    SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;                            //Important !!! Specifies the output Window
    SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    SwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;


    //Create Swapchain
    ThrowIfFailed(factory->CreateSwapChain(commandQueue, &SwapChainDesc, (IDXGISwapChain**)&swapchain),
        "Failed to create Swapchain");


    //Query Interface
    ThrowIfFailed(swapchain->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&swapchain)),
        "Failed to Query Interface to Swapchain4");


    // Create RTV Descriptor Heap
    D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC rtvHeapDesc = {};
    rtvHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;
    rtvHeapDesc.NodeMask = 0;
    rtvHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = 2;
    rtvHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV;

    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&rtvHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&rtvHeap)),
        "Failed to Create RTV Descriptor Heap");


    //Populate RTV Descriptor Heap
    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE cpu_handle = rtvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
    for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
    {
        ThrowIfFailed(swapchain->GetBuffer(n, IID_PPV_ARGS(&rtBuffers[n])),
            "Swapchain::GetBuffer Failed!");

        device->CreateRenderTargetView(rtBuffers[n], nullptr, cpu_handle);

        //Increment cpu_handle
        cpu_handle.ptr += device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
    }

    // Shader Compliation

    ID3DBlob* vertexShader;
    ID3DBlob* pixelShader;

#if defined (_DEBUG)
    UINT compileFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#else
    UINT compileFlags = NULL;
#endif

    //VertexShader
    ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", nullptr, nullptr, "main", "vs_5_0", compileFlags, 0, &vertexShader, 0),
        "Failed to Compile PixelShader");

    //Pixel Shader
    ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(L"PixelShader.hlsl", nullptr, nullptr, "main", "ps_5_0", compileFlags, 0, &pixelShader, 0),
        "Failed to compile Pixel Shader");


    // Create Vertex Buffer

    float VB_Data[] =
    {
         0.0f   ,  0.25f,
         0.25f  , -0.25f,
        -0.25f  , -0.25f
    };

    //Heap Properties
    D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES RessourceProperties = {};
    RessourceProperties.Type = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD;
    RessourceProperties.MemoryPoolPreference = D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN;
    RessourceProperties.CPUPageProperty = D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN;
    RessourceProperties.CreationNodeMask = 0;
    RessourceProperties.VisibleNodeMask = 0;

    //Resource Description
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC RessourceDesc = {};
    RessourceDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    RessourceDesc.Alignment = 0;
    RessourceDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    RessourceDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    RessourceDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    RessourceDesc.Height = 1;
    RessourceDesc.Width = sizeof(VB_Data);
    RessourceDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    RessourceDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    RessourceDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
    RessourceDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;

    //Create Upload Heap
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &RessourceProperties,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &RessourceDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&VertexBuffer)),
        "Failed to Create CommittedResource")

    //Map
    float* pSharedData;
    ThrowIfFailed(VertexBuffer->Map(0, nullptr, (void**)&pSharedData),
        "Failed to Map Vertex Buffer");

    //Copy
    memcpy(pSharedData, VB_Data, sizeof(VB_Data));

    //Unmap
    VertexBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);

    //Define View
    VertexBufferView.BufferLocation = VertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    VertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = sizeof(VB_Data);
    VertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = sizeof(float) * 2;


   // Create Root Signature

    ID3DBlob* RootBlob;
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC Root_Desc = {};
    Root_Desc.Flags = D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT;
    Root_Desc.NumStaticSamplers = 0;
    Root_Desc.NumParameters = 0;

    //Serialize Root Signature
    ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&Root_Desc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &RootBlob, nullptr),
        "Failed to Serialize Root Signature")


    //Create Root Signature
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateRootSignature(0, RootBlob->GetBufferPointer(), RootBlob->GetBufferSize(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&RootSignature)),
            "Failed to Create Root Signature")


    // Create Pipeline State Object

    //Input Layout
        D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDescs[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    //PSO Description
    D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC PSO_Desc = {};

    PSO_Desc.InputLayout = { inputElementDescs, _countof(inputElementDescs) };

    PSO_Desc.pRootSignature = RootSignature;

    PSO_Desc.VS.BytecodeLength = vertexShader->GetBufferSize();
    PSO_Desc.VS.pShaderBytecode = vertexShader->GetBufferPointer();

    PSO_Desc.PS.BytecodeLength = pixelShader->GetBufferSize();
    PSO_Desc.PS.pShaderBytecode = pixelShader->GetBufferPointer();

    PSO_Desc.NodeMask = 0;

    PSO_Desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    PSO_Desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    PSO_Desc.Flags = D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_FLAG_NONE;

    PSO_Desc.RasterizerState.FillMode = D3D12_FILL_MODE_SOLID;
    PSO_Desc.RasterizerState.CullMode = D3D12_CULL_MODE_NONE;

    PSO_Desc.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
    PSO_Desc.NumRenderTargets = 1;
    PSO_Desc.RTVFormats[0] = SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format;

    //Create PSO
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&PSO_Desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&PSO)),
        "Failed to Create PSO");

    //Create Fence
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateFence(0, D3D12_FENCE_FLAG_NONE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&Fence)),
        "Failed to Create Fence");

    //Create Command List
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommandList(0, D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, commandAllocator, PSO, IID_PPV_ARGS(&commandList)),
        "Failed to create Command List")

    commandList->Close();
}




void Process::Render()
{
    if (swapchain)
    {
        //Reset Command List and Allocator
        commandAllocator->Reset();
        commandList->Reset(commandAllocator, PSO);

        //Set Viewport and Viewport Rect
        D3D12_VIEWPORT Viewport = {};
        D3D12_RECT ViewRect = {};
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &ViewRect);

        Viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
        Viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
        Viewport.MinDepth = 0;
        Viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
        Viewport.Height = ViewRect.bottom - ViewRect.top;
        Viewport.Width = ViewRect.right - ViewRect.left;

        commandList->RSSetViewports(1, &Viewport);
        commandList->RSSetScissorRects(1, &ViewRect);

        //Set Root Signature
        commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(RootSignature);

        //Indicate that Backbuffer will be used as Render Target
        D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER rb1 = {};
        rb1.Type = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE_TRANSITION;
        rb1.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAG_NONE;
        rb1.Transition.pResource = rtBuffers[swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex()];
        rb1.Transition.Subresource = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_ALL_SUBRESOURCES;
        rb1.Transition.StateBefore = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT;
        rb1.Transition.StateAfter = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET;
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &rb1);

        //Set RenderTargets
        D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE cpu_handle = rtvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
        cpu_handle.ptr += swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex() * device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
        commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &cpu_handle, false, nullptr);

        //Clear Render Target View
        const float clearColor[] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
        commandList->ClearRenderTargetView(cpu_handle, clearColor, 0, nullptr);

        //Draw Triangle
        commandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
        commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VertexBufferView);
        commandList->DrawInstanced(3, 1, 0, 0);

        //Indicate that Backbuffer will now be used to Present
        D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER rb2 = {};
        rb2.Type = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE_TRANSITION;
        rb2.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAG_NONE;
        rb2.Transition.pResource = rtBuffers[swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex()];
        rb2.Transition.Subresource = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_ALL_SUBRESOURCES;
        rb2.Transition.StateBefore = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET;
        rb2.Transition.StateAfter = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT;
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &rb2);

        //Execute Command Lists
        commandList->Close();
        commandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(1, (ID3D12CommandList* const*)&commandList);

        //Wait For Command Queue
        Fence->Signal(0);
        commandQueue->Signal(Fence, 1);

        while (Fence->GetCompletedValue() == 0)
        {

        }

        //Present
        swapchain->Present(1, 0);
    }
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
float4 main( float2 pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
    return float4(pos, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
float4 main() : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I don't see any code in your post?

Comment: I provided the entire project as hyper link to google drive ... and my project is already whats defined as an minimal reproducible example ... problem is that its like 600 lines of defining the DX12 Objects, that all just serve to draw a triangle on the screen, so i don't think it would be a good idea to copy paste that into the question

Comment: Code must be contained within the question otherwise the whole question becomes unusable when the link dies

Comment: changed it, hope its better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `BlendState` in the `Pipeline` State Object was not defined(but initialized). After doing so the triangle was visible.

Answer (score 2):

*Welcome to graphics programming with DirectX 12!*

One of the things that makes graphics programming a challenge is debugging. It's often hundreds or thousands of lines of code, and a single error can result in a 'blank screen'.

A few recommendations:

- Be wary of 'tight loops' like this which can tie up CPU resources doing useless work.

  ```
    while (Fence->GetCompletedValue() == 0)
    {

    }
  ```
- For DirectX 12 programming, you should look at using the modern Shader Model 6 compiler instead of legacy `D3DCompileFromFile`. You should also consider using offline compilation.
- You can render directly from an UPLOAD heap, but the recommendation is to move the VB/IB data to DEFAULT memory instead.

From looking at your code, one problem may be a lack of a resource barrier for the vertex buffer. The [common-state promotion](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d12/using-resource-barriers-to-synchronize-resource-states-in-direct3d-12) may be handling this for you, but the debug layer should be able to verify the behavior.

Since you didn't include your shader code, we can't help you debug that. You can end up with a 'missing triangle' for any number of reasons in there as well.

You should take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTrianglePC12) and see where you differ.

> You should take a look at these basic rendering loops for DirectX 12 on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for best practices.

Comment: I provided the entire Project in an Hyper Link ( so you should find the Vertex Shader & Pixel Shader files there, also i know that the current state of my project is Inefficent, but the only purpose i have for it is to draw a triangle on the screen, and understanding the process behind it ...

Comment: I also Added the Vertex and Pixel Shader to the Questions ... they are very simple

Comment: I think your vertex shader return value could be incorrect. Try returning `float4(pos, 0, 1)`. You're probably not outputting a visible triangle to clip space if the _w_ component of your vertex coordinates is zero.

Comment: Changed it to that, but the problem persists